# Short Answer Matrix in Google Forms

Tags: google-forms

I'm trying to figure out some way to have a short-answer matrix functionality with Google Forms, like in the below Qualtrics image:

[image]

Does anyone know if there's any way this could be possible?

I know it isn't available in the "question selection" screen, but I'm wondering if there's some sort of add-in or background shenanigans that might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a `Multiple-choice Grid` question

[image]

or a `Tick box Grid` question

[image]